# which is more lazy, click or scrolling?

Tags: design-patterns, click, scroll

In browsing a website for search results(let's say search results are songs/movies), if for each click one gets new list of result, which is a more lazy and still gives most results:click or scroll?

P.S. This is for a laptop/desktop environment.

Comment: i hope it should be scroll

Comment: i personally find scrolling as lazy way and still getting more information for every scroll. Clicking too much gets irritating. But it could be my personnel taste. Other people might have different opinion.

Comment: On a laptop, I would use the keyboard. Or ask one of my servant to scroll for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm speaking from my own experience with that matter:

You will get much more user engagement if you implement "infinity scroll". Instead of paginating search results load first 100, then as persons scrolls down, load 50 more with AJAX call. Scrolling does not get your user off the page, so there is no mental decision to make - "am I done with that? Should I go to the next page?" So users will be inclined to stick longer to your website.

This way of delivering information "stream" is becoming more and more common these days. See Twitter, FB, Yahoo, even 9Gag :-)

There is also back side of that, although your user engagement will go up, you will find it's more challenging to advertise on this page with infinite scroll. You will find that it's harder to track what user has seen and did not like vs. seen and liked. Lack of tracking will directly impede your ability to improve on your search results.